# Permission issue when publishing a website using web deploy

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, teamcity, webdeploy

I am trying to publish a website using WebDeploy but I am getting the following error:

```
08:58:43]Step 1/1: New build step (MSBuild) (1m:54s)
[08:58:45][Step 1/1] BodyLogic.build.teamcity: Build target: Deploy (1m:52s)
[08:58:45][BodyLogic.build.teamcity] Deploy (1m:52s)
[09:00:36][Deploy] CallTarget (1s)
[09:00:36][CallTarget] DeployLocal (1s)
[09:00:36][DeployLocal] Exec (1s)
[09:00:37][Exec] EXEC (9/25/2013 9:00:37 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
[09:00:37][Exec] EXEC Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File")  for the specified directory ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bodylogicmd.development\App_Data\Dependencies\Orchard.Alias.dll"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
[09:00:37][Exec] EXEC The error code was 0x80070005.
[09:00:37][Exec] EXEC Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bodylogicmd.development\App_Data\Dependencies\Orchard.Alias.dll' is denied.
[09:00:37][Exec] EXEC error count: 1.
[09:00:38][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf80143fdcf7709\BodyLogic.build(48, 5): error MSB3073: The command "".\Tools\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf80143fdcf7709\Build\package\BodyLogic.Orchard.zip" -dest:iisApp="bodylogicmd.development",computerName=127.0.0.1:8172" exited with code -1.
[09:00:38][BodyLogic.build.teamcity] Project BodyLogic.build.teamcity failed.
[09:00:38][Step 1/1] Step New build step (MSBuild) failed
```

I am trying to go to IIS and configure the website deploy user, but when I go to the site, and right click on it, I don't have an option called: Deploy -> Configure for Web Deploy Publishing or anything like that, I just have:

```
Deploy -> Export Application
Deploy -> Import Application
Deploy -> Delete Web Site and Content
Deploy -> Recycle
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Also all the user "Everyone" has full control on the website folder.